# Simplify $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Simplify $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I have manage to arrive to $$\frac{x^3+2x+2x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(x^2+2)\sqrt{x^2+1}+2x^2+2}$$

But Wolfram [manage](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%20%281%2Bsqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29) to simplify to $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: Have you tried to factor an $x$ out of the numerator and denominator? Or better yet an $x^2 + 2%=$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Expand the fraction with $1-\sqrt{x^2+1}$:

$$\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}  =\frac{x^2(1-\sqrt{x^2+1})}{1-(x^2+1)} = \sqrt{x^2+1}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $t:=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ so $\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{t^2-1}{1+t}=t-1$ has derivative $\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.